# How to remove temp tables from logic in stored procedure query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I need to improve the stored procedure sample code shown here to remove all temp tables, by using one query code or CTE maybe?

Note that it is necessary to create the first temp table to get specific users ID list, then create the second temp table with another specific criteria, then join with both temp tables created to get the final results table.

```
SELECT    
    Column_1,
    Column_2,
    Column_3    
INTO 
    #TempTable_1    
FROM
    TABLE_1    
WHERE 
    Column_1 = 1

SELECT    
    Column_1,
    Column_4,
    Column_5,
    Column_6    
INTO
    #TempTable_2    
FROM 
    TABLE_2    
WHERE 
    Column_4 = 4    

SELECT
    A.Column_1,
    A.Column_2,
    A.Column_3,
    B.Column_4,
    B.Column_5,
    B.Column_6    
FROM
    #TempTable_2 B    
INNER JOIN 
    #TempTable_1 A ON A.Column_1 = B.Column_1
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove your temp tables? What are you hoping to gain from it?

Comment: Join corrected, it's between the two temp tables.

Comment: @DaleK my sql server admin setup can not accept temp tables within a stored procedure, they cause performance issues.

Comment: How do you know they cause performance issues? Usually its the other way around...

Comment: Anyway, you can just replace your temp table references with the query you use to populate them.

Comment: It is a restriction set by my sever admin, can you explain more? how to replace? will be great if you can write it in code. Thanks.

Comment: Its called a sub-query e.g. `FROM #TempTable_2 B` becomes `from (select ...) B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Dale's sub-query, you can use a CTE

```
with cte1 as (
SELECT    
    Column_1,
    Column_2,
    Column_3    
FROM TABLE_1    
WHERE Column_1 = 1
),  cte2 as (
SELECT    
    Column_1,
    Column_4,
    Column_5,
    Column_6    
FROM TABLE_2    
WHERE Column_4 = 4    
)
SELECT
    A.Column_1,
    A.Column_2,
    A.Column_3,
    B.Column_4,
    B.Column_5,
    B.Column_6    
FROM cte2 B    
INNER JOIN cte1 A ON A.Column_1 = B.Column_1
```

Comment: Syntactical sugar :) we're all sub-queries here

Comment: @DaleK  Yes, but I suspect OP needed a little nudge  :)